# Pyspark create new column based on condition

Tags: python, pyspark

Hello I am totally new to pyspark and I dont know how to do this.

I read a csv file in a pyspark dataframe using

```
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("Python Spark SQL basic example") \
    .config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value") \
    .getOrCreate()

df = spark.read.option("header",True).csv("input.csv")
```

The CSV looks like this

```
ID NAME
1  A
2  B
3  C
```

I have another txt file called `ids.txt` which is just a list of ids

```
1
2
```

My task is to add a new column to the `input.csv` file based on whether the id in that row is present in `ids.txt`
My output should look like this

```
ID NAME NEW_COL
1  A     1
2  B     1
3  C     None
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do following
Assuming `df1` is first table and `df2` is second table

```
df2 = df2.withColumn(‘NEW_COL’, f.lit(1))
```

Now,

```
df1 = df1.join(df2, on=[‘ID’], how=‘left’)
```

And that is that!

Comment: I have to read the ids.txt into df2? And then these two steps?

Comment: @KaushikKaralgikar yes